# Mockito verify order / sequence of method calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Is there a way to verify if a `methodOne` is called before `methodTwo` in Mockito?

```
public class ServiceClassA {
    public void methodOne(){}
 }

public class ServiceClassB {
    public void methodTwo(){}
 }
```

---

```
public class TestClass {
    public void method(){
        ServiceClassA serviceA = new ServiceClassA();
        ServiceClassB serviceB = new ServiceClassB();
        serviceA.methodOne();
        serviceB.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 433, accepted):

[`InOrder`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#inOrder(java.lang.Object...)) helps you to do that.

```
ServiceClassA firstMock = mock(ServiceClassA.class);
ServiceClassB secondMock = mock(ServiceClassB.class);

Mockito.doNothing().when(firstMock).methodOne();   
Mockito.doNothing().when(secondMock).methodTwo();  

//create inOrder object passing any mocks that need to be verified in order
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(firstMock, secondMock);

//following will make sure that firstMock was called before secondMock
inOrder.verify(firstMock).methodOne();
inOrder.verify(secondMock).methodTwo();
```

Comment: This is correct, though the calls to doNothing are not needed here except as a placeholder for other stubbing. Mockito will silently accept void method calls by default.

Comment: It accept them while the object have no dependencies if the object have dependencies there will be an exception =)

Comment: consider `inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();` after the last verify in this example to verify that no other calls were made.

Comment: Just to clarify: It is safe to define inOrder just before verify - after invoking some (tested) methods on mocks.

Comment: Are the results the same for `inOrder(firstMock, secondMock)` and `inOrder(secondMock, firstMock)`?  Perhaps you can update the answer to make a note about this.

Comment: You can also use the same mock in multiple calls of `inOrder.verify(...)` with different methods inside that mock.

Answer (score 141):

Note that you can also use the [InOrder](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/InOrder.java) class to verify that various methods are called in order on a single mock, not just on two or more mocks.

Suppose I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
public class Foo {
  public void first() {}
  public void second() {}
}

public class Bar {
  public void firstThenSecond(Foo foo) {
    foo.first();
    foo.second();
  }
}
```

I can then add a test class to test that `Bar`'s `firstThenSecond()` method actually calls `first()`, then `second()`, and not `second()`, then `first()`. See the following test code:

```
public class BarTest {
  @Test
  public void testFirstThenSecond() {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    Foo mockFoo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
    bar.firstThenSecond(mockFoo);

    InOrder orderVerifier = Mockito.inOrder(mockFoo);
    // These lines will PASS
    orderVerifier.verify(mockFoo).first();
    orderVerifier.verify(mockFoo).second();

    // These lines will FAIL
    // orderVerifier.verify(mockFoo).second();
    // orderVerifier.verify(mockFoo).first();
  }
}
```

Comment: This should have been a comment on the accepted answer, not a whole new answer.

Comment: I disagree with your comment @ach  The code sample helps, so a new answer makes sense.

Comment: Is there a way to verify the same method is called twice, but the verify the order of the parameters passed in?  e.g. First `find('foo')`, then `find('bar')`

Comment: Looks like this might be my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573399/how-to-verify-invocations-of-the-same-mock-method-with-the-same-argument-that-ch

Comment: @Snekse Actually, you don't need to capture the arguments at all. Capturing is usually done to verify attributes of an object passed to a method when you don't know what that argument will be. For your case, you do know the values being passed, namely `"foo"` and `"bar"`. So you just need to add those arguments to your method call after you call `verify()`. So for your case, the code for the answer above would have the test code changed to have a line like the following: `firstThenSecondVerifier.verify(mockFoo).find("foo")`. I just verified that that code works for Mockito in an offline test.

Comment: @entpnerd, it worth to mention that `find("foo")` right after `find("foo")` should be checked mode `times(2)`. But `find("foo")`, `insert("foo")`, `find("foo")` can be checked in 3 lines with single-invocation verification mode in their order.

Comment: @ony thanks for your contribution. I think that I did a poor job of conveying the intention of this answer. I'm trying to convey how to test the order of method calls, without regard to duplicate calls. I think that discussing duplicate calls of `first()` mildly detracts from the answer's intention. As per your comment, I have added more prose to better explain the intention of the answer. That being said, I really like your idea of discussing duplicate method calls, but I think that that discussion is best left for a separate answer, which I would be happy to upvote. :-)

Comment: This is actually a better example than the accepted answer because it shows a more typical usage than `doNothing()`

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @ArchimedesTrajano.

Answer (score 44):

Yes, this is described in the documentation. You have to use the [InOrder](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/InOrder.java) class.

Example (assuming two mocks already created):

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(serviceAMock, serviceBMock);

inOrder.verify(serviceAMock).methodOne();
inOrder.verify(serviceBMock).methodTwo();
```

Answer (score 7):

For Kotlin users, you can go this way:

```
class MyTrackerTest {
    private val trackEventUseCase: TrackEventUseCase = mock()
    private val sut = MyTracker(trackEventUseCase)

    @Test
    fun `trackSomething SHOULD invoke tracker use case twice with correct event names WHEN called`() {
        sut.trackSomething()

        trackEventUseCase.inOrder {
            verify().invoke("Is it August?")
            verify().invoke("No!")
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

With BDD it's

```
@Test
public void testOrderWithBDD() {


    // Given
    ServiceClassA firstMock = mock(ServiceClassA.class);
    ServiceClassB secondMock = mock(ServiceClassB.class);

    //create inOrder object passing any mocks that need to be verified in order
    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(firstMock, secondMock);

    willDoNothing().given(firstMock).methodOne();
    willDoNothing().given(secondMock).methodTwo();

    // When
    firstMock.methodOne();
    secondMock.methodTwo();

    // Then
    then(firstMock).should(inOrder).methodOne();
    then(secondMock).should(inOrder).methodTwo();


}
```

Comment: wthat is `willDoNothing()` doing there? Where is the reference? Why is it preceeding?

Answer (score 0):

When verifying the invocation order of a single method call with different arguments it's essentially the same:

```
ServiceClass myMock = mock(ServiceClassA.class);

InOrder inOrder = inOrder(myMock);

inOrder.when(myMock).myMethod(42);
inOrder.when(myMock).myMethod(69);
```