# how to assert orders of calls to one single mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to write a junit test with mockito

say this is my mock:

```
IServerApi routingServerApi = mock(ServerApi.class);
        when(routingServerApi.sendRequest(anyString(), eq("request1"))).thenReturn(myObj1);
        when(routingServerApi.sendRequest(anyString(), eq("request2"))).thenReturn(myObj2);
```

I want to verify that `sendRequest` is called with `request1` just before it's called with `request2` (and no other invocation between them).

How can i do this?

I have seen this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901368/mockito-verify-order-sequence-of-method-calls) question,

but I want to verify order of calls to just one mock, not two.

This syntax doesn't work for me (compilation error when initing `inOrder()`)

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mockRoutingServerApi);

inOrder.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRtUpdates(time1, ImmutableList.of("update1"));
inOrder.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRoutingRequest("request1");
inOrder.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRtUpdates(time1, ImmutableList.of("update2"));
inOrder.verify(mockRoutingServerApi).sendRoutingRequest("request2");
```

It doesn't recognize `inOrder()`

[image]

Some commented I can use `ArgumentCaptor` but I couldn't see how.

Comment: What does error message says? Your code looks right and shouldn't give any compilation error since `inOrder(Object... mocks)` receive varargs.

Comment: it doesn't recognize inOrder() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArgumentCaptor` can be used instead of `InOrder` for checking received values.

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
verify(mockRoutingServerApi, times(2)).sendRoutingRequest(captor.capture());
```

And then you can check waht is passed to `sendRoutingRequest`

```
captor.getAllValues() //Should be a List with values {"request1", "request2"}
```

This looks more like inventing a wheel since `Mockito` supports `InOrder.verify`.
Make sure you have a static import for `Mockito`. Otherwise try `Mockito.inOrder(routingServerApi)`.

Comment: It doesn't recognize `inOrcer()` init method

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this. 
The issue may be that you have to import both the InOrder class AND the inOrder method ie;

```
import org.mockito.InOrder;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.inOrder;
```

The method should then be recognised if you add the second import above.

---

Another way to do this (which is doing the same thing really) is import

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
```

and call the method from the class ie

```
InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockRoutingServerApi);
```

Hope this helps!