# How to create rule for method invocation

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules, method-invocation

I'm creating a rule to check if two methods get invoked.
It will get non-compliant if `sendRedirect()` method gets invoked after the `getParameter()` method.

```
String location = req.getParameter("url");
resp.sendRedirect(location);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you use smth like `Mockito`?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik with mockito you can check whether something has been called, and how many times, but I doubt you can check the exact order in which something was called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901368/mockito-verify-order-sequence-of-method-calls

Comment: @oleg.cherednik yes, it can check for the order, but the exact order. I might be wrong in understanding the question, but does it also test whether or not there was an(y) other call in between them?

Comment: I think it would be better, if the rule tests if the parameter of `Request#sendRedirect()` is from `Response#getParameter()` without any other methods(that change it between the calls)