# Unit Testing the SEQUENCE of values emitted from a single livedata

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I want to unit-test the sequence of a LiveData's results. I have a `result` LiveData which emits values when loading, success, or error. I want to test it to ensure that loading value is emitted first, then the success or error value.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, I'll include an example which is using the [mockk](https://github.com/mockk/mockk) library. Let's say that you have a ViewModel and a LiveData<Your_type_here> `result`. You have to add a mocked observer (androidx.lifecycle.Observer) which values will be verified.  In your test you'll have a class-level variable

```
@MockK
lateinit var observer: Observer<Your_type_here>
```

Then in the @Before (or if you have only one test, you can paste it there) function you should add this

```
viewModel.result.observeForever(observer)
every { observer.onChanged(any()) } just Runs
```

And in the test you'll have something like

```
// given - your mocking calls here
// when 
viewModel.doSomethingAndPostLiveDataResult()
// then
verifySequence {
    observer.onChanged(Your_type_here)
    observer.onChanged(Something_else)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there an equivalent of verifySequence in Mockito?

Comment: @AmrSalah as far as I remember, they have InOrder class for such cases. Haven't used Mockito for a while, but here is a big useful thread about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901415/19580355