# Is it possible to verify the same method with different parameters 2 times in kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, mockito

The method will be called two times with different parameters:

1. `method("test1")`
2. `method("test2")`

In my test I am trying to check if the parameters are right or not

```
`when`(
    mockClass.method(
        anyObject()
    )
).then { param ->
    val value: Class = param.arguments[0] as Class
    assert(value == "test1")
}


`when`(
    mockClass.method(
        anyObject()
    )
).then { param ->
    val value: Class = param.arguments[0] as Class
    assert(value == "test2")
}
```

I understand why it is not working but is there a proper way to verify the same method two times?

I am trying to verify the same method which will be called two times with different parameters and want to check if are given parameters are right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you want to assert that something is called with some parameter then use `verify` not `when`->`assert`.
And you can write multiple verify's in a row like.

```
verify(mockClass).method("test1")
verify(mockClass).method("test2")
```

You can also use `inOrder` to verify correct order. More is described here for example: [Mockito verify order / sequence of method calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901368/mockito-verify-order-sequence-of-method-calls)